# C#: How to use Interface with dapper ORM

Tags: c#, dapper

I have complex application to DB operations I am using Dapper Micro-ORM, I want to make loosely coupled code. Please suggest how can i use interface instead of class with dapper. 
I have following code :

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Find()
    {
        using (IDbConnection _conn = GetConnection)
        {
            _conn.Open();
            return _conn.Query<Category>("usp_Category", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
```

I want to replace with

```
public IEnumerable<ICategory> Find()
    {
        using (IDbConnection _conn = GetConnection)
        {
            _conn.Open();
            return _conn.Query<ICategory>("usp_Category", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do with `Dapper` and `C#` is incorrect:

```
_conn.Query<ICategory>("usp_Category", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

You are trying to fetch `IEnumerable<ICategory>`, which will not work out, since `ICategory` is an `interface` and that cannot be filled as you are expecting, you can at most get is: `IEnumerable<Category>`. You cannot initialize an `ICategory interface` like a concrete class, which is not possible

```
ICategory ic = new ICategory();
```

`IEnumerable<ICategory>` is not the correct usage, and can neither be fetched through any means, to understand that you need to understand the difference between an `interface` and `concrete` class and their usage

Answer (score 0):

Even though you want to loosely couple your code, at some point you are going to have to create a concrete implementation of each ICategory instance.

In the example you provided, the Dapper call will be where that happens. Dapper will take the data from the query (over a connection of type IDbConnection implementation, so there's some loose coupling there) and translate each row into a Category instance.

The "Find" method will return an IEnumerable<Category>, consisting of these concrete implementations. However, because IEnumerable<T> is covariant, IEnumerable<Category> may be cast to IEnumerable<ICategory>.

This allows your "Find" method to have a return type of IEnumerable<ICategory>, meaning that the consumers of that method need not know anything more than they are getting a set of ICategory implementations back (Dapper needs to know what concrete type to populate but the callers of the Find method do not need to know what ICategory implementation will be returned).

Your code need only be changed slightly:

```
public IEnumerable<ICategory> Find()
{
    using (IDbConnection _conn = GetConnection())
    {
        return _conn.Query<Category>("usp_Category", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
}
```

(Note that I removed the `_conn.Open();` line since Dapper will open the connection for you, if it is not already open).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Loosely coupled code, we could use generic implementation which will consume your ORM Repository with generic Repository pattern.

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> items = null;
        using (DbConnection cn = this.Connection)
        {
            cn.Open();
            items = cn.Query<T>("Select * from [TableName]");
        }

        return items;
    }
```

You can find the library which will have generic implementation using ASP.NET Core under GitHub [link](https://github.com/inventsoftlabs/MicroORM-Dapper)